# What is WordPress file encoding?

Tags: customization, encoding, coding-standards

I noticed that WordPress files use UNIX end-of-line and UTF-8 without BOM. Is this a standard that should be used? Is there anything else to pay attention to?

I noticed that Filezilla fails to transfer Macintosh end-of-line files properly to Windows or Linux servers. New line endings are missing. And sometimes they are doubled with different configuration. I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this encoding and the Unix line endings is enforced by Subversion. I know it is with Git

Comment: @bungeshea Valuable piece of information! So UNIX encoding is preferred - why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UNIX line endings (`\n`) and UTF-8 are just common code standards. As far as I can see, they are not even mentioned in the [Coding Standards](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/). Most (all?) core PHP files are just plain US-ASCII. Try to follow that path to keep your files as compatible as possible.

If you use UTF-8, add a line at the start of a PHP file with an *[Encoding Cookie or file variable](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables):*

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Many editors (Emacs, Vim, Sublime, Scite) will use that to set the proper encoding automatically.

I have also seen:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8-unix -*-
```

But I am not sure how compatible it is.

Comment: Whnever I report issues possibly related to file encoding in WordPress Trac they mention to switch to UTF8 without BOM to have wider range of characters available. Well, I would be happy to see breakdown of possibilities in Codex and one recommendation but I'm not a guru to write it myself yet :) For now I'll keep using what WP uses. It seems like their hidden standard.

Answer (score 2):

PHP itself does not care whether you use DOS or UNIX style line endings in the PHP code sections, because it simply ignores whitespace anyway, so both of those get ignored regardless.

PHP interpreters do not know about the existence of Byte Order Marks in files, and so having a BOM at the start of the PHP file will cause that BOM to be output when the PHP file is executed. This is often undesirable, and so PHP files in general cannot have a BOM in them.

PHP files don't care about encoding, they simply produce output as-given for most cases, and thus anything outside the PHP sections can be more or less anything, including straight binary output for all PHP cares. For maximum compatibility and portability, UTF-8 without a BOM is recommended.

WordPress uses Unix style line endings for preference, however submissions to the plugin repository are not checked for one style or the other. Use whichever you like. Submissions to the theme repository are checked for mixed line-endings, which means a file which has both Unix and DOS style line endings in it. This often happens when copy and pasting code using certain Mac editors. These mixed line endings can cause problems in Subversion repositories, so the theme uploader will reject files with mixed line endings. Plugin authors, having direct access to their SVN repositories, will receive similar failures from SVN when uploading mixed-up files themselves.

Comment: I'd also like to mention that using for instance `<header>  <?php echo the_title(); ?>  </header>` in themes, if the inner content of `<header>` has new lines and indentation in template files caused me these tabs and new lines being displayed but perhaps encoding has nothing to do with it and it will always be like that. Tabs need to be avoided if I wanted to use `header:empty { }` in CSS.

Comment: And another problem I faced is that when moving files between systems (computer -> server or server -> computer) line endings duplicate or disappear. This seems not to ever happen with UNIX line endings.